# How to call adminCreateUser from React front-end?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I would **only** like my "Supervisor" user to be able to create "Employee"  users (unable to create their own) through a custom React App rather than go through the Cognito Console. The AWS Cognito Identity SDK's [AdminCreateUser action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html) is offered through [AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html), which seems more than available through a [Node back-end](https://www.stackery.io/blog/authentication-aws-cognito/) and the [AWS Management Console interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-user-accounts.html?shortFooter=true). And there is (teasingly) plenty of documentation on authenticating users that have *[already been created](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-identity-user-pools-javascript-example-authenticating-admin-created-user.html?shortFooter=true)* through the AdminCreateUser API.  But, try to

```
import { CognitoIdentityServiceProvider } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
```

And AFAIK (as far as I know), the action is not provided in React.

Comment: what is the question?  You know how to call the API.  So is the question "how to restrict access to adminCreateUsers to a specific group of users (supervisor) ?  If this is the question, it is not a Cognito question.  It relates how do you authenticate users, assign them to groups and check authorisations after login.  The API ListGroups, ListUsersInGroup are likely to help here

Comment: @SébastienStormacq my primary question is in the title. There *doesn't* seem to be a straightforward way to reach the API from React, so I'm still figuring out what stack I'll need (if I'll need something more than what create-react-app provides). Do I need to be running my React app on the cloud (probably going with Amplify) *over* a Node.js server? Or can I somehow call a Node.js script from React?

Comment: I also noticed that "AdminCreateUser requires developer credentials." Does this mean that my client's Supervisor-level user should have developer privileges? That seems excessive... but is that the only way they can call that action programmatically?

Comment: So, if the question, is how to call these API from React, the answer is to use the AWS SDK for Javascript in the browser https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/ . There is no specific SDK for React.  Amplify will help you and simplify React integration by providing you some higher level API for Cognito User Pool and Storage for example, but does not expose all API, like the one you want to use.

Comment: Developer credential means AWS User credentials, i.e. a role with permissions allowing them to call that API

Comment: @SébastienStormacq I was able to get SDK to work for me, although I'm still hitting hiccups often (SMS 2FA). I wouldn't have known that that's what "developer credentials" meant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm considering using a hacky approach of defining 2 particular Cognito User Pool - User Groups *Supervisor* and *Employee*. Only users that belong to the *Supervisor* group will be able to access a registration screen (using [protective React Routing](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)) where the I can use the well-documented [CognitoUserPool](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js) sub-SDK to create *Employee* users.

Comment: I'm not marking this as correct because I am sure this process can be improved.